# Adding custom widget area to menu in Wordpress Theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

i am using business one wordpress theme, i want to place a notice with bigger and bold text in the menu, so i created a menu item and added a new css class.

```
.myclass {
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 24px;
 pointer-events: none;
 cursor: default;
}
```

`

This class only makes the menu item font bolder but the color and size stay the same?? Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your style could be overwritten byt the themes default style.
Try to write the style with the parent tags like

```
nav ul.classname .myclass {
  /* Style*/
}
```

If it doesn't work then only use !important to write the style like

```
nav ul.classname .myclass {
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #fff !important;
 font-size: 24px !important;
 pointer-events: none;
 cursor: default;
}
```